# How to sort a a "date" of string type in sort function of realm

Tags: swift, sorting, realm

I'm using Swift as the language. I use Realm as my database for my app. In that app database I have one table (entity) and 10 fields (attributes). Two relevant fields are the occasion fields and the other one is the date. Both data are of type String. Now I am preparing a view controller with a tableview which will display a query which will give a result of occasions and their respective dates. The problem is that I want to sort the occasions using the associated date in ascending manner but the sort   cannot sort the "dates" ascending as it is in a string format  (eg "11/01/2019"). It will only sort the dates according to the first 2 digits i.e. day and not the months and year. Can you help me? The code I am using :

```
 caseClasses = realm.objects(BasesClass.self).filter("occasion = 'Wedding'").sorted(byKeyPath: "date", ascending: true)
```

So how do I sort "date" in the byKeyPath. I've got the "string to Date conversion" code but I do not know how to implement it to that code.

```
let dateString = realm.objects(BasesClass.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "nextDate", ascending: true)
   let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
   let dateFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: "\(dateString)")
```

Thank you.

Comment: If this is your database why don't you change the type of `nextDate´ to Date instead? It must be the best solution in the long run.

Comment: I was hoping for other solution as changing the data type would mean I have to change a lot of codes for different view controllers. This is the last part of my codes. I’m about to finish the app. And this is the only place I need the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Your best move here is to change how the date is stored in Realm; either use a Date object or a string object of "yyyymmdd". It really shouldn't be too much to change that over as once you read the object in, it's easily formatted with a DateFormatter to whatever you need for display. The issue is you want to sort the data in Realm, not in code so if the data is not in a good format for sorting in Realm, you're stuck. Make the change now while it's easier.

Comment: Yes Jo, I think I have to make the change of the data type from string to date type. Like you’ve said It is the best long term solution.  Thanks again.